# NavController и global actions - не работают при клике на пункты меню

Tags: android, navigationbar, navigation

Проблема следующего рода: создал приложение на основе Navigation Drawer. Получил граф переходов. Для каждого фрагмента в графе - назначил Global action, которая описывает анимацию при входе и выходе из фрагмента.

Если вызывать вот так, (например, по клику на кнопку):

```
Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(R.id.action_global_nav_devices);
```

т.е. вызывать action напрямую - то всё чудесно, анимация перехода работает. Но при этом - совершенно не работает анимация переходов при клике на пунктах меню Drawer. Связываются они, ясное дело, штатным образом:

```
DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
    // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
    mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
            R.id.nav_status, R.id.nav_sensors, R.id.nav_devices,
            R.id.nav_settings, R.id.nav_share, R.id.nav_send)
            .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
            .build();

navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
```

Подозреваю, что система в этом случае просто не выполняет global action для пункта меню.

Вопрос: как это дело вылечить, и дать понять системе, что при клике на пункт меню - я однозначно хочу выполнить action, привязанный к этому пункту меню?

Comment: Вопрос запутанный разными терминами до ужаса... Если вы хотите выполнить действие при нажатии на пункт меню из `NavigationView`, то вам нужно переопределить метод  `onNavigationItemSelected`

Comment: Действие - и так выполняется NavController автоматически, при клике пункта меню. Вопрос простой: можно ли без переопределения методов дать понять NavController, что при клике на пункте меню надо выполнять определённый action? Если просто прописать ID этого action в AppBarConfiguration.Builder - то не работает, крэшится приложение.

Comment: Лучше бы в вопрос добавили код, ожидания от кода, и лог падения.

Comment: В вопросе код есть. Ок, вводные простые: есть два фрагмента, fragment1 и fragment2. На fragment2 есть кнопка, по клику перемещаемся на fragment1 способом, приведённым выше. Global action при этом отрабатывает, т.к. она привязана к fragment1. При этом по клику меню в NavigationView - вызова global action, привязанной к fragment1 - не происходит, очевидно, почему - в AppBarConfiguration прописаны ID меню, а не ID action. Вам какой код нужен? Код конфигурации - я привёл, объяснения - тоже, тот, кто работал с графом Navigation - легко поймёт, о чём речь.